# Pass parameter to function in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Here is my activity:

```
class PlayerDetails : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {
    ...
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player_details)
        val intent = getIntent()
        numOfPlayers = intent.getIntExtra("number_of_players", 1)
        next_details.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        for (i in 1..numOfPlayers) {
                ...
                nextUser()

            } else {
                blankFields()
            }

        }
    }
    private fun nextUser() {

    }

}
```

How do I pass the value of `i` in my for loop to `nextUser()`?

I tried `nextUser(num: Int = i)` but it doesn't work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Change your method to accept a parameter

```
private fun nextUser(num: Int) { }
```

And call the function like this

```
for (i in 1..numOfPlayers) { ... nextUser(i) } else { blankFields() } }
```

Comment: Your parameter name is num, you should use num in the method, not i

Answer (score 0):

Your nextUser should look like as follow:

```
private fun nextUser(i: Int = DEFAULT_VALUE) {

}
```

DEFAULT_VALUE is optional, if you choose you can delete `= DEFAULT_VALUE` from you function definition. In that case, you always need to pass value when you make a call to `nextUser`.

Then, from your for loop you can pass `i` value to `nextUser` as follow.

```
for (i in 1..numOfPlayers) {
    ...
    nextUser(i)

} else {
    blankFields()
}
```

Comment: tre `var nu: Int = 5 + num`

Answer (score 0):

The `NextUser()` function must accept one input param.

Now the Code is like

```
for(i until numOfPlayers) {
   nextuser(i)
}
else {
   blankFields()
}
```

Now the `nextUser` looks like.

```
nextUser(value : Int) {
    TODO("perform the action")
}
```